# Laravel CLI - connect to DB with prompted credential

Tags: php, laravel-5, command-line-interface

I would like to ask user for DB credential (on the CLI) before the application connect to the database.

Example:

```
> php artisan db:administrate

> Please enter DB username:
> dbUser

> Please enter the DB password:
> ******
```

And then if the credential are OK, the handle() method of the AdministrateCommand would be fired.

Is it possible to do that with Laravel ?

Any clue ou idea would be much appreciate :)

Thank in advance.

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys I found a solution.

Here is it:

```
    // This is my database.php 
    'connections' => [
        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],    
    ],
```

Then in my command file

```
    $connectionName = 'sqlsrv';

    $dbUser = $this->ask('DB username: ');
    $dbPassword = $this->secret('DB password: ');

    // get the current database configuration
    $connectionConfig = \Config::get("database.connections");

    // update the credential
    $connectionConfig[$connectionName]['username'] = $dbUser;
    $connectionConfig[$connectionName]['password'] = $dbPassword;

    // update the DB connection.
    \Config::set("database.connections.".$connectionName."", $connectionConfig[$connectionName]);
```

Now if the user enters bad credentials he won't be able to get anything from the DB.